# How rewrite this js file in magento2

Tags: magento2

```
// Global Namespace
var test=
{
}
```

i am using this but not working

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'abc_def/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cryozonic_stripe':'my_module/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cryozonic_stripe'

        }

    }
};
```

but not woking

Comment: you wan't to overrite the js file right ?

Comment: try to put ( " " ) in map

Comment: "map": { ......

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure your module is enabled:

> php bin/magento module:status Vendor_Module

2. Make sure your **requirejs-config.js** is under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend folder
3. Remove **var/view_preprocessed** and **pub/static/frontend** folders
4. Run this command to clear caches:

> php bin/magento c:c

Comment: every thing is ok

Comment: still not working